# How to deploy airflow using kubernetes and kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kustomize, airflow-webserver, kompose

I'm running minikube and I want to deploy airflow using [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) instead of helm.

So first I got the docker-compose.yaml

```bash
curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.0/docker-compose.yaml'
```

Then I execute [`kompose convert`](https://kompose.io/), to convert the docker-compose to kubernetes yaml.

After I change the service files to `type: LoadBalancer`.

Then I deploy all those file generated by the kompose, all pods are running.

I start minikube tunnel

I was expecting to get the airflow ui on the url localhost:8080

However I'm getting

```
The connection was reset
```

What am I doing wrong?

I try to change the ports from 8080 to 8060

I saw the logs for each pod using `kubectl logs <pod-name>` but no error appear

I try using the url generate by this cmd

```bash
minikube service airflow-webser --url
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml that I modify to work with kompose

```yaml
---
version: '3'
# x-airflow-common:
#   image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
#   environment:
#     AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
#     AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
#     AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
#     AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
#     AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
#     AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
#     AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
#     AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
#     AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
#     _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
#   volumes:
#   - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
#   - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
#   - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
#   user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0
#   depends_on:
#     - redis
#     - postgres

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
    - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
    - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0

    command: webserver
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - airflow-init

  airflow-scheduler:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0

    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - airflow-init

  airflow-worker:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
    volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test: 
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - airflow-init
  
  airflow-triggerer:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - airflow-init

  airflow-init:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
    - -c
    - |
      function ver() {
        printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
      }
      airflow_version=$$(AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO && gosu airflow airflow version)
      airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
      min_airflow_version=2.2.0
      min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
      if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
        echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres

  airflow-cli:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
    volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    # profiles:
    # - debug
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - airflow
  
  flower:
    image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.5.0}
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
      AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    user: ${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0
    command: celery flower
    # profiles:
    # - flower
    ports:
    - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5554/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - airflow-init

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Comment: did you try to access the UI using `http://EXTERNAL_IP:8080`? (you can get it from the LoadBalancer service `kubectl get svc`)

Comment: yes, I also tried
minikube service airflow-webserver --url

Comment: It looks like `kompose convert` doesn't support much of the syntax used in the Airflow `docker-compose.yaml`. Can you include your modified `docker-compose.yaml` in your question? That would allow us to generate the same set of manifests, which would in turn allow us to try to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Also, there appears to be [an official helm chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) for installing Airflow on Kubernetes; why are you mucking about with `kompose convert`?

Comment: because I want to use kustomize without having to use helm, because I don't want too much abstraction on the yaml files that we get using templates of helm

Comment: @DevScheffer Did you resolve your issue? The closest I can find is installing the plugin for helm chart on kustomize. Here is a reference: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md

Comment: Yes, basically I get the helm chart than generate the manifest with values. using the cmd ```helm get manifest <chart-name> > manifest.yaml ```